# Stack buffer overrun exception ONLY when compiled by Qt Creator c++

Tags: visual-studio-2013, compilation, qt-creator

I have a piece of code that uses a camera api. I built the GUI around it with Qt. Everything was fine until my windows did not boot any more and I had to reinstall everything. now

When I compile my code and run the code with visual studio **(without qt files, just to communicating with api)**, it runs perfectly(32bit x86).

However when I use Qt Creator **(exactly same code)**, (MSVC 32bit Kit with CDB debugger, with qmake for 32 bit):

- in release mode I get the error:

> The program has unexpectedly finished.

- In debug mode:

> *** A stack buffer overrun occurred in
>   C:\yourproject\build-testQT-Desktop_Qt_5_3_MSVC2013_OpenGL_32bit-Debug\debug\testQT.exe:
>
> This is usually the result of a memory copy to a local buffer or
>   structure where the size is not properly calculated/checked. If this
>   bug ends up in the shipping product, it could be a severe security
>   hole. The stack trace should show the guilty function (the function
>   directly above __report_gsfailure).  *** enter .exr 77F8F9A8 for the
>   exception record  *** then kb to get the faulting stack

Could someone help me please. Why is it running in VS not QtC? Is it jom against nmake?

**EDIT** The code has no bugs at is the sample code that comes with the vendor and was working perfectly before I had to reinstall VS and Qt

Thanks

Comment: Most likely it's down to one or more latent bugs in your code. Try stress testing - run under valgrind, etc.

Comment: Do you get any warnings when building? If you enable more warnings, do you get any then? Warnings are often a sign of you doing something you should not be doing, and can point to places where you have [*undefined behavior*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) which can, for example, lead to stack problems.

Comment: Hey Joachim, No warnings at all